# I need to create a softlayer network firewall rule through REST API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to create a softlayer network firewall rule through REST API.
I have referred the Softlayer documents but still I'm unabe to create a firewall rule.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this REST request to add Firewall rules ([SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request/createObject)):

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request/createObject
```

Method: POST

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "firewallContextAccessControlListId": 2854,
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "permit",
          "destinationIpAddress": "any",
          "destinationIpCidr": 0,
          "destinationPortRangeEnd": 80,
          "destinationPortRangeStart": 80,
          "notes": "This is a test",
          "orderValue": 1,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "sourceIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
          "sourceIpCidr": 0,
          "version": 4
        },
        {
          "action": "permit",
          "destinationIpAddress": "50.97.51.242",
          "destinationIpCidr": 32,
          "destinationPortRangeEnd": 80,
          "destinationPortRangeStart": 80,
          "notes": "This is an API test 2",
          "orderValue": 2,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "sourceIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
          "sourceIpCidr": 0,
          "version": 4
        },
        {
          "action": "permit",
          "destinationIpAddress": "50.97.51.240",
          "destinationIpCidr": 32,
          "destinationPortRangeEnd": 80,
          "destinationPortRangeStart": 80,
          "notes": "This is an API test 3",
          "orderValue": 3,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "sourceIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
          "sourceIpCidr": 0,
          "version": 4
        },
        {
          "action": "permit",
          "destinationIpAddress": "any",
          "destinationIpCidr": 0,
          "destinationPortRangeEnd": 8080,
          "destinationPortRangeStart": 8080,
          "notes": "This is an API test 4",
          "orderValue": 4,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "sourceIpAddress": "2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7339",
          "sourceIpCidr": 128,
          "version": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Where:** The old rules have to configured in the above `body request` and add the `new rule`. In my case, I ‘m adding this new rule:

```
{
      "action": "permit",
      "destinationIpAddress": "50.97.51.240",
      "destinationIpCidr": 32,
      "destinationPortRangeEnd": 80,
      "destinationPortRangeStart": 80,
      "notes": "This is an API test 3",
      "orderValue": 3,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "sourceIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
      "sourceIpCidr": 0,
      "version": 4
    }
```

To know the meaning of properties in `rules` section, please see: [SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule)

### Update 1:

Also, to get **`firewallContextAccessControlListId`**, please see:

If you know the `firewall_id`, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/[firewall_id]/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[id,firewallRules,firewallInterfaces[id,firewallContextAccessControlLists]]

Method: GET
```

The response in my case is:

```
{
"id": 204016
"firewallInterfaces": [2]
0:  {
"id": 5678
"firewallContextAccessControlLists": [0]
}-
1:  {
"id": 5679
"firewallContextAccessControlLists": [1]
0:  {
"direction": "in"
"firewallContextInterfaceId": 5679
"id": 2854
}
}
…
```

**Reference:** [SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall::getNetworkVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/getNetworkVlans)

Otherwise, if you don't know the `firewall_id`, you can list all `Network_Vlan_Firewall` adding some masks:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch?objectMask=mask[resource(SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall)[id,primaryIpAddress,networkVlans[id,firewallInterfaces[firewallContextAccessControlLists]]]]
```

Method: POST

Json Payload:

```
{
"parameters": [
"_objectType:SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall"
]
}
```

The response should be similar to the last request, but for all items.

Note: In this case we are using `v3.1` instead of `v3` in the request because `advancedSearch` service works only for `v3.1`.

Comment: While doing request for adding Firewall Rules in post data you are passing "firewallContextAccessControlListId"   where you got this id?

Comment: @Sandeshbm, I sent you the request to get this `firewallContextAccessControlListId`. But now, improved it in **`Update 1`** section of the answer and also, I added other request can help you. Regards.

Comment: @mcruz The service http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule does not seem to have a delete method. Any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: This method will *replace* all rules with the one(s) supplied.

Comment: As it turns out, it is not possible to *just add* or *just remove* a firewall rule in the SoftLayer solution. So with hundreds of virtual hosts that are running hundreds of servers on the same VLAN, very large rulesets need to be sent back and forth, making an on-demand system that updates rules as needed in real-time quite... clunky.

Answer (score 0):

take a look this codes let me know if you need more information

```
# Edit Vlan firewall rule.
#
# A firewall's ruleset is modified by passing a SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request template
# object to SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request::createObject. The entire ruleset is rewritten
# with each update request. This means it is necessary to include all past unchanged rules along with any
# modifications or additions. This is easily accomplished by pulling in the existing rules as described above
# then modifying the gathered array.
# Each SoftLayer_Network_Component_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule object requires:
#
# action - permit or deny
# destinationIpAddress - destination address
# destinationIpSubnetMask - subnet mask for destination
# sourceIpAddress - originating address
# sourceIpSubnetMask - subnet mask for origin address
# protocol - tcp/udp
# destinationPortRangeStart - first port the rule will effect
# destinationPortRangeEnd - last port the rule will effect
# orderValue - order in which rules are applied (lower is sooner)
#
# Important manual pages:
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request/createObject
# @License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# @Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer.API

# For nice debug output:
import pprint

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
#
# Generate an API key at the SoftLayer Customer Portal

API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

vlanId = 211163
# Create the client object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
objectMask = 'mask[firewallRules,firewallInterfaces[firewallContextAccessControlLists]]'
vlan = client['SoftLayer_Network_Vlan'].getObject(mask=objectMask, id=vlanId)
rules = vlan['firewallRules']

firewallContextAccessControlListId = ''
# Getting the ID of Access Control List.
# Each VLAN will have two types of firewallInterface: 'inside' and 'outside'.
# firewallContextAccessControlLists are organized by a direction of 'in' or 'out'.
# Currently the SoftLayer Platform supports the 'outside' firewallInterfaces
for firewall in vlan['firewallInterfaces']:
    if firewall['name'] == 'inside':
        continue
    for controlList in firewall['firewallContextAccessControlLists']:
        if controlList['direction'] == 'out':
            continue
        firewallContextAccessControlListId = controlList['id']
try:
    # Modifying a rule
    ipToAllow = '119.81.91.198 '
    index = 0
    for rule in rules:
        if rule['sourceIpAddress'] == ipToAllow:
            rule['action'] = 'permit'
            rules[index] = rule
        index += 1
    updateRequestTemplate = {
        'firewallContextAccessControlListId': firewallContextAccessControlListId,
        'rules': rules
    }
    updateRequestClient = client['SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request'].createObject(updateRequestTemplate)
    pprint.pprint('Rule updated!')

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error updating the rule  faultCode=%s, faultString=%s"
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

..

```
# Edit Standard Rule
# A rule set of a firewall is modified by passing a SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request template object
# to SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request::createObject. The entire rule set is rewritten with each
# update request. This means it is necessary to include all past unchanged rules along with any modifications
# or additions. This is easily accomplished by pulling in the existing rules as described above then modifying
# the gathered array.
# Each SoftLayer_Network_Component_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule object requires:
#
# action - permit or deny
# destinationIpAddress - destination address
# destinationIpSubnetMask - subnet mask for destination
# sourceIpAddress - originating address
# sourceIpSubnetMask - subnet mask for origin address
# protocol - tcp/udp
# destinationPortRangeStart - first port the rule will effect
# destinationPortRangeEnd - last port the rule will effect
# orderValue - order in which rules are applied (lower is sooner)
#
# Important manual pages:
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request/createObject
# @License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# @Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
#
# Generate an API key at the SoftLayer Customer Portal
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Create the client object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

serverId = 5439388
objectMask = "mask[firewallServiceComponent[rules]]"
server = client['Virtual_Guest'].getObject(mask=objectMask, id=serverId)

try:
    # Modifying a rule
    if 'firewallServiceComponent' in server:
        ipToAllow = '192.168.1.1'
        index = 0
        if 'rules' in server['firewallServiceComponent']:
            rules = server['firewallServiceComponent']['rules']
            for rule in rules:
                if rule['sourceIpAddress'] == ipToAllow:
                    rule['action'] = 'deny'
                    rules[index] = rule
                index += 1
            updateRequestTemplate = {
                'networkComponentFirewallId': server['firewallServiceComponent']['id'],
                'rules': rules
            }
            updateRequestClient = client['SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request'].createObject(
                updateRequestTemplate)
        print("Rule updated!")
    else:
        print("The server does not have firewall component")

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error updating the rule  faultCode=%s, faultString=%s"
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```