# SoftLayer API createObject

Tags: api, rules, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, createobject

I've been trying for several days to get the API Service {'Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].createObject
working without success. I did get the firewallManager edit_dedicated_fwl_rules working but now want the Service to work too. I've looked throughout the web for an answer and could not find one.

My question is what is the syntax of the arguments to pass to the Service createObject for the Firewall Rules?
Do you have an example?

The command being used is:

```
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=user, api_key=api)
client['Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].createObject(id=12345, [{'action': 'permit'}])
```

yes, I know I need more rule statements for a create.
This returns `"SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" because of the "id=".`

Putting the `"id="` at the end of the API:
`client['Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].createObject([{'action': 'permit'}], id=12345)
then the error is "Either a component ID or an ACL ID must be supplied."`

If I remove the "id=" and only have 
`client['Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].createObject(12345, [{'action': 'permit'}])`

then the error is "Either a component ID or an ACL ID must be supplied."

I know I must have the `"id="` as this command works:

`client['Network_Firewall_Update_Request'].getRules(id=12345)`

But with the Manager API command `fw.edit_dedicated_fwl_rules(12345, [{'action': 'permit'}])`

there is no `"id="` as this creates the rule successfully.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

check this post:

[I need to create a softlayer network firewall rule through REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468319/i-need-to-create-a-softlayer-network-firewall-rule-through-rest-api)

Well a REST example to create a rule is like this:

```
POST https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request/createObjec

Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "networkComponentFirewallId": 72605,
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "permit",
          "destinationIpAddress": "159.8.52.188",
          "destinationIpCidr": 32,
          "destinationPortRangeEnd": 122,
          "destinationPortRangeStart": 12,
          "notes": "This is a test",
          "orderValue": 1,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "sourceIpAddress": "10.10.10.0",
          "sourceIpCidr": 32,
          "version": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to replace all the value according the configuration that you need.

Now you need to get the "networkComponentFirewallId" for the request above, that can be get like this:

```
GET https://$USERID:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VSIID/getFirewallServiceComponent
```

Using Python the example above will be something like this:

```
client['Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].createObject(
 {
          "networkComponentFirewallId": 72605,
          "rules": [
            {
              "action": "permit",
              "destinationIpAddress": "159.8.52.188",
              "destinationIpCidr": 32,
              "destinationPortRangeEnd": 122,
              "destinationPortRangeStart": 12,
              "notes": "This is a test",
              "orderValue": 1,
              "protocol": "tcp",
              "sourceIpAddress": "10.10.10.0",
              "sourceIpCidr": 32,
              "version": 4
            }
          ]
        }
)
```

and to get the "networkComponentFirewallId" property:

```
client['Virtual_Guest'].getFirewallServiceComponent(id=VirtualGuest)
```

Note that the examples above are to edit the rules  of a firewall attached to a VSI.

In order to create a rule for a dedicated firewal in a VLAN this is the request:

```
client['Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].createObject(
{
    "firewallContextAccessControlListId": 3092,
    "rules": [{
        "action": "permit",
        "destinationIpAddress": "any",
        "destinationIpCidr": 32,
        "destinationIpSubnetMask": "255.255.255.255",
        "destinationPortRangeEnd": 65535,
        "destinationPortRangeStart": 1,
        "id": 5669281,
        "orderValue": 1,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "sourceIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "sourceIpCidr": 0,
        "sourceIpSubnetMask": "0.0.0.0",
        "status": "allow_edit",
        "version": 4
    }]
}
)
```

Now how to get the value for "firewallContextAccessControlListId", you need to use this:

```
client['SoftLayer_Network_Vlan'].getFirewallInterfaces(id=vlanId, mask="mask[firewallContextAccessControlLists]")
```

The method above will return the interfaces outside and inside, currenlty only you can set the rules for the outsitde inteface

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your response Nelson.  I had found that example, but it didn't work.  The format they used was "firewallContextAccessControlListId": 2854,  "rules": which did not use the "id=" when passing the value. Using this format returns the error is "Either a component ID or an ACL ID must be supplied."

Comment: I will review it and let you know, but the code worked nice before

Comment: I updated my answer, jut one thing to point out the createObject methods does not have as parameter an id, you need to pass that ID in the payload in some cases the parameter name will be named id, but in other as this case the id of the firewall is called networkComponentFirewallId. Also it woul be help more to know what kind of firewall you are dealing with

Comment: Also i updated my code in the other answer an both are working fine regards

Comment: Thanks again for a detailed response.  This structure of the command is quite evident now.  Of course I'm not using the VSI attached firewall and am working with a VLAN - dedicated firewall.  :)  
Based on your description and the referenced link about I use the client['SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request_Rule'].getObject(id=fw_id) and get 'networkComponentFirewallId': fw_value.  
But this must not be the correct parameter for the VLAN - dedicated firewall as command still fails wanting a component ID.  I did try many other permutations of the parameter without success.

Comment: look at my code (in the first post link I pass you), it contains the following information # Getting the ID of Access Control List.
# Each VLAN will have two types of firewallInterface: 'inside' and 'outside'.
# firewallContextAccessControlLists are organized by a direction of 'in' or 'out'.
# Currently the SoftLayer Platform supports the 'outside' firewallInterfaces Basically for VLAN firewall you need to use the firewallContextAccessControlListId value please see the code I will try to update this post with that information later