# Opening Specific Ports - REST API Possibility

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have laucnhed an Instance and I need to open specific ports for the instance ,
I can't see any options in the Softlayer console after launching . But there is a API doc [here](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/activatePublicPort) .

I would like to know whether it is possible to add port via API , if so please post the pattern of the json.

Answer (score 0):

For call that method you only need to do a get request

```
GET https://$APIUSER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VSIID/activatePublicPort
```

Note: replace $APIUSER, $APIKE and $VSIID

Regards

Comment: How do I open specific ports with this API , like 8080 alone , cuz the  API which you gave doesn't have port value .

Comment: The API cannot open the ports in the OS, the API only can intereact with firewalls such as Vyatta nexScalers etc. if you cannot open the ports via COntrol portal UI you will not be able to do it via API.

Comment: I am also asking the ports in the firewall . But there is option only to enable and disable firewall not to open specfic ports over the firewall .. I m not asking to open ports in OS level  , just to open ports over softlayer firewall.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468319/i-need-to-create-a-softlayer-network-firewall-rule-through-rest-api there is a exmaple using python for create the rules you need to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Update_Request/createObject method to create the rules